# KDB+ 32 bit free version is not saving our work?

Tags: kdb

I have installed free 32 bit version in my system. When ever I do some work (create tables, insert data into tables..etc.), it is storing the data for that particular session only.

If I login again, I could not see the created tables at all. Is there any limitation with KDB+ free version?

Comment: kdb+ does not have sessions similar to Oracle or MS SQL Server. All changes are global to an instance and immediately visible to all clients. How do you login? Are you sure you don't terminate kdb+ process each time?

Comment: After installing it, I got q.exe. its opening a command line with 'q>'.
Session means I am referring that command line only.

Comment: If you are new to kdb I advise going through the tutorials at: http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-database-intro and those on code kx. kdb has a steep learning curve that the tutorials can help make easier.

Comment: "Session means I am referring that command line only". If you terminate q.exe by typing `\\` or `exit 1` or by closing a command prompt window and then start a new instance then yes, you will lose all your data. kdb+ is not going to save its state automatically, you need to do it explicitly.

Comment: @IgorKorkhov Yes. What do you mean by explicitly? I am using 'save' command to save tables. But it is storing outside of the database as like file system (I can store table as flat files). My doubt is how can I store tables in KDB+ itself.

Comment: @RyanHamilton Thanks. I have gone through those tutorials already. I am in the process of learning KDB+ now.

Comment: @NaveenReddyCH: you can't store tables "in KDB+ itself". Kdb+ is very different from say Oracle, MS SQL, MySql etc. There's no single huge file which hosts all tables, views, stored procedures and what not. A kdb database is just a directory with a bunch of tables in it and you can have as many databases as you like.

Answer (score 0):

To save them 'in KDB' the best way to go about this is to save the tables you wish using the SET keyword

`` q)`:user\kdb\mytable_fileLocation set actual_table ``

(Look at code.kx.com or QforMortals) and then when you are logging into a new q session you can use the steps laid out here
http://code.kx.com/nwiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/loading_tables_from_stored_data

to load in data. Personally I prefer

```
C:\> q
q) \l table_name
```

for loading in tables